# Using Python Descriptors to Trigger on Class Members' Content

Tags: python, descriptor

I have a simple Python class:

```
class Car:
    self.dirty = False
    self.owner = 'Alice'
    self.wheels = []

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
         self.dirty = True
         super(Car, self).__setattr__()
```

After some experimenting, I see `__setattr__` is called only when *setting* `owner` or `wheels`:

```
car_instance.owner = 'Bob'
car_instance.wheels = []
```

It does not get called when *appending* to `wheels`:

```
wheels.append(wheel_instance)
```

This does not surprise me, and I understand why it is not being called.

**I am just wondering how I would get it to be called for the 3 scenarios I listed:**

```
car_instance.owner = 'Bob'     # SCENARIO 1
car_instance.wheels = []       # SCENARIO 2
wheels.append(wheel_instance)  # SCENARIO 3
```

I've experimented a bit with the different descriptors, but no luck. I ultimatley just want to set `dirty = True` when a class member is modified (set, reset, modified, appended to, etc.).

Comment: I think you would need to put whatever side effect you want in a function that is called from both the `__get__` and `__set__` methods of the descriptor used for the attributes. However, there is no way (short of introspection on the code itself) to determine from inside `__get__` what is subsequently done with the object.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this using only descriptors. Full stop.

You have to provide a custom list class which does what you want. This is not too difficult if your custom list inherits [collections.abc.MutableSequence](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html). As you can see, you can get away by "only" implementing `__getitem__`, `__setitem__`, `__delitem__`, `__len__`, `insert`—the others are filled in by the abstract base class `MutableSequence`.

Use a normal list as backing storage and implement the methods using that.

Note that the index argument to `__setitem__`, `__getitem__` and `__delitem__` can be a [slice](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#index-64), which are more tricky to implement than you’d expect. I recommend a tight test suite.

Once you have your list class, you use it as the type for your class’ attributes (you can control the type using `@property` or custom descriptors, by preventing the user from assigning any other type).